# The show must have come back/come back on

Tags: word-usage, phrases

So here, my mom turns to another channel,because the show I was watching went on a break. So I wanted her to turn back to my show again. So what should be used:

> The show must have come back.

Or

> The show must have come back on.

What sounds natural:come back/come back on?

What would you use if none sounds natural,any better alternatives?
Thank you:)

Comment: A tip: the modal verb **must** here means "I believe that". So you wrote "I believe that the show has come back". The word **must** can have different meanings!

Answer (score 2):

"Must have" is used for things that you deduce or believe:

> Peter *must have* come downstairs for water last night. He left his glass on the table.

So saying "The show must have come back" means "I have deduced that the show has come back".  If this is what you intend to say, it is correct.

There is not much difference between "come back on" and "come back". I prefer "come back on" as we often use "is on" to mean "has started" in the context of tv programmes "My show is on", for example.  But I'd probably use both.

Comment: From the prelude to the question, it sounds to me that the questioner *does* intend to say, "I have deduced that the show has come back"... or "back on" (from the break). Hence "must have" is appropriate. I myself do not know about the "back" or "back on" question, or I would submit an answer.

Comment: You,are right @Lorel C. Actually that's what I meant to say. My mom switched to her programme,when my show went on a break. So after I while I feel that it must have come back/come back on. And is the use of "come back" or "come back on" natural?